# Publishing a value calculated in a function in ROS

Tags: python, ros, carla

I am working on ROS for an autonomous driving system. I have defined and calculated a value 'priority' in a function as follows:

```
def odometry_weight_model(velocity, orientation, steering_angle):
    """Odometry based camera view prioritization model"""
    rospy.loginfo(velocity)
    rospy.loginfo(orientation)
    rospy.loginfo(steering_angle)
....
for yaw_ang in CAM_LOC:
        force_dir = yaw_ang + steer_angle
        force = np.array([velocity, force_dir])
        delta = (np.linalg.norm(force)) / (2 * math.pi) * const
        **priority = prio_orig + delta**
```

Now, I want to publish the value in ROS via the publisher I have defined. I created a new topic and have used the 'Float32' type from the 'std_msgs.msg' pack since the 'priority' is a float value. My attempt for the publisher is as follows:

```
def main():
    """Run the view prioritization"""
    rospy.init_node("view_prioritization", anonymous=True)

    role_name = rospy.get_param("~role_name", "ego_vehicle")
    sensor_definition_file = rospy.get_param(
        "~sensor_definition_file",
        "$(find telecarla_manual_control)/config/multi_sensors.json",
    )

    global CAM_LOC
    with open(sensor_definition_file) as sensor_data:
        multi_sensors = json.load(sensor_data)
        CAM_LOC = []
        for i in multi_sensors["sensors"]:
            camera_loc.append(i["yaw"])

    pub = rospy.Publisher(
        "/carla/{role_name}/camera/rgb/view/priority",
        Float32,
        queue_size=10,
    )
    rospy.Subscriber(
        "/carla/{role_name}/vehicle_status",
        CarlaEgoVehicleStatus,
        vehicle_status_callback,
    )
    rate = rospy.Rate(1)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        pub.publish()
        r.sleep()

    rospy.spin()
```

In the above code - I am creating this topic - /carla/{role_name}/camera/rgb/view/priority - and would like to publish the value of 'priority' to this topic - however, I have not been able to figure out a way to do it, I am still stuck at how to send this priority value on my topic by using only the Float32 type from the msg pack. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit of a noob myself, you aren't creating a Float32 msg to publish.

msg=Float32(some value)

pub.publish(msg)

Take a look at the basic ROS publisher/subscriber tutorial - it is exactly what you want

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29